# Identity relation vs Reflexive Relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So we're starting relations in my discrete structures class this week, and I've probably read this over 10 times by now...I believe I have a good understanding of Identity Relations, but Reflexive Relations seem to have me slightly confused.

From my understanding, an example of Identity relation using set $A = \{1,2,3,4\}$

1. $R_1 = \{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4)\}$ because each element is equal to itself.
2. $R_2 =\{ (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (1, 4)\}$ would not be an identity relation, as $1 \neq 4$.

What I don't understand is why

> The relation $R_2$ defined by $R_2 = \{(1, 1), (3, 3), (2, 1), (3, 2)\}$ is not a reflexive relation on $A$, since $(2, 2) \notin R_2$.

is not a Reflexive Relation

Could someone give me an example of what a simple reflexive relation is, and isn't?

**Thanks all for the input, see below for a good example of a Reflexive Relation**

Here's what the book describes both as:

**Identity relation.**

> Let $A$ be any set. Then the relation $R = \{(x, x) : x \in A\}$ on $A$ is called the identity relation on $A$. Thus, in an identity relation, every element is related to itself only.
>
> For example, consider $A = \{a, b, c\}$ and define relations $R_1$ and $R_2$ as follows.
>   $R_1 = \{(a, a) ,(b, b), (c, c)\}$
>   $R_2 = \{(a, a), (b, b), (c, c), (a, c)\}$

Then $R_1$ is an identity relation on $A$, but $R_2$ is not an identity relation on $A$ as the element $a$ is related to $a$ and $c$.

**Reflexive relation.**

> A relation $R$ on a set $A$ is said to be a reflexive relation if every element of $A$ is related to itself. Thus, $R$ is reflexive iff $(x, x) \in R$ for all $x \in A$.
>   A relation $R$ on a set $A$ is not reflexive if there is an element $x \in A$ such that $(x, x) \notin R$.
>   For example, consider $A = (1, 2, 3)$. Then the relation $R_1$ defined by $R_1 = \{(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (1, 3), (2, 1)\}$ is a reflexive relation on $A$.
>   The relation $R_2$ defined by $R_2 = \{(1, 1), (3, 3), (2, 1), (3, 2)\}$ is not a reflexive relation on $A$, since ($2, 2) \notin R_2$.
>   Remark
>
> Every identity relation on a non-empty set $A$ is a reflexive relation, but not conversely. Consider $A = \{a, b, c\}$ and define a relation $R$ by $R = \{(a, a), (b, b), (c, c), (a, b)\}$. Then $R$ is a reflexive relation on $A$ but not an identity relation on $A$ due to the element $(a, b)$ in $R$.

Comment: If you keep asking questions like this, with this level of detail and patience, you will be a fabulous mathematician.

Comment: I recommend reading my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1743037/why-is-the-relation-r4-reflexive/1743090#1743090) where I give a graph theoretic way to interpret the definitions of reflexivity, symmetry, antisymmetry, and transitivity.

Comment: An identity relation is just a special case of a reflexive relation that contains no further data. That is, you can think of the identity relation on a set as the "smallest" reflexive relation on the given set. We can formalize this intuition in many ways, one of them is to say that an identity relation on a set $A$ is the intersection of all reflexive relations on $A$.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A relation $R$ on $A$ is reflexive if $(x,x)\in R$ for every $x\in A$.

So if $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$ the following **are** all reflexive:

1. $R=\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4)\}$
2. $R=\{(1,1), (1,2), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4)\}$
3. $R=\{(1,1), (1,3), (2,2), (2,3), (2,4), (3,3), (4,1), (4,4)\}$

Each of the above contains $(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)$ and $(4,4)$, making them reflexive. Note that 1. is the identity, and it is reflexive. However, the following **are not** reflexive:

4. $R=\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,1), (4,4)\}$
5. $R=\{(1,1)\}$
6. $R=\{(1,1), (1,3), (1,4),(2,1), (2,2), (3,1), (3,3), (4,3)\}$

In 4. $R$ does not contain $(3,3)$ so it is not reflexive. In 5. $R$ does not contain $(2,2), (3,3),$ or $(4,4)$ so it is not reflexive. In 6. $R$ does not contain $(4,4)$, and hence it not reflexive either.

Comment: Exactly the type of answer I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Re-read your definition of a reflexive relation $R$:  **Every** element must be related (under $R$) to itself.  In your example, since we don't have $R(2,2)$ $R$ can't meet this definition.

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly... with my previous example of identity relation of A = {1,2,3,4) would be 

R1 = (1,1) (2,2) (3,3) (4,4) is an identity relation
R2 = (1,1) (2,2) (3,3) (4,4) (1,4) is not a identity relation, but reflexive?

Comment: @beatles1235 your R2 is indeed reflexive.  You will find that it is also transitive and antisymmetric, but not symmetric.  In fact, all reflexive relations contain the identity relation as a subset.

Comment: So with reflective relation, I can have an element that is not related to itself, as long as i have at least all elements related to itself. Does that sound correct?

Comment: @beatles1235 Your example has all elements related to itself.  It also has an element related to a different nonequal element.  Just because one of the comparisons (in this case (1,4)) is between two unequal things, the fact that all are related to themselves does not change.  A better way to say your first line is "I can have an element that is related to an element other than itself"

Comment: perfect! if you feel like putting that into an answer, i'd totally accept that!! thank you for helping me understand that!

Comment: @beatles1235: You may also find the following observation helpful. If $D$ is the identity relation on a set $A$, then a relation $R$ on $A$ is reflexive if and only if $D\subseteq R$. That $\subseteq$ means that $R$ has to contain all of the pairs $\langle a,a\rangle$ with $a\in A$, but it can contain other pairs as well.

Answer (score -2):

Let,
 a,b € Z
(a, a) € R.
Then, a-a=0
=(a-a) is divisible by 2
Z={1,2,3}.
So, Z×Z
=R={(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(1,3).    ["R" is reflexive relation]
I={(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)}.     [where, "I" is Identity Relation]
So,from the above example  we can notice that :-
Reflexive relation- is a kind of relation which contains the elements related to itself  as well as can contain other pairs too. 
Identity Relation- is a kind of relation which contains the elements related to itself only.
**Thus, "Every IDENTITY Relation on a Non-Empty set is a REFLEXIVE Relation but not vice-versa....

Comment: I would suggest editing the answer to make it look more presentable.

Comment: Beyond just formatting, I can't figure out what's going on in the first three sentences.