# Is this relation reflexive/symmetric/antisymmetric?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

So I have this exercise in my discrete math course that I don't understand:

Put $A = \{1,2,3\}$ and form the relation R on A by putting $R = \{(1,1),(2,2),(1,2),(2,3),(3,1)\}.$

Investigate if $R$ is: reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric. If the relation has a property, give proof for it and if the relation doesn't have the property, prove it.

My attempt:

Reflexive: Yes, since $\{1,2,3\} = \{1,2,3\}.$

Symmetric: No, because in R every sub-pair of elements has max 2 elements and thus doesn't contain $\{1,2,3\}.$

Anti-symmetric: No ... but don't know why.

There is no hindsight but I know I'm wrong, can someone please help me out?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: the relation is neither reflexive nor symmetric nor transitive,that's  just a binary relation

Comment: $R$ being reflexive means for each $a\in A,$ $(a,a)\in R.$ Is $(3,3)\in R?$

Comment: "*Yes, since $\{1,2,3\}=\{1,2,3\}$*"  The domain being the same as the codomain is irrelevant here.  To be reflexive requires that for every element $x$ in the domain $(x,x)$ is an element of the relation.  Here, $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$ are both elements of the relation however $(3,3)$ is not.  As such it is not true that *every* element $x$ satisfies that $(x,x)$ is in the relation and so it is not reflexive.

Comment: I recommend thinking about problems like these from a graph-theoretical point of view.  [See this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1743037/why-is-the-relation-r4-reflexive/1743090#1743090) for instance on some of the interpretations.  It is plain to see in your example that all arrows (*not loops*) are single-sided and so the relation is antisymmetric.

Comment: Can someone please explain why this relation is anti-symmetric? Anti-symmetry means aRb ^bRa if and only if a=b. How does it apply to this case?

Answer (score 2):

Not reflexive as $(3,3) \notin R$.

Not symmetric as $(1,2) \in R$ but $(2,1) \notin R$.

The relation is anti symmetric.

Not transitive as $(1,2),(2,3) \in R$ but $(1,3) \notin R$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for noting the typo!

Comment: Thank you for answering. But could you please explain why it is anti-symmetric? And also, why would (1,3) have to be in R for it to be transitive?

Comment: Regarding transitive, please refer to the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation?wprov=sfti1). Regarding anti symmetric, notice that for any $a\neq b$, you never have both $(a,b) \in R$ and $(b,a) \in R$.

Comment: I still do not understand why this relation is anti-symmetric. Anti-symmetry means aRb ^bRa if and only if a=b.  How does it apply to this case?

Comment: @JeanDoe For what integers $a,b$ do you both have $(a,b)\in R$ and $(b,a) \in R$?